# matplotlib - Pyplot - Subplot / Diagrammwith wrong values and outliers in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, subplot

I try my first steps with pyplot.

My actual result is good enough for me, but I have a problem with the main subplot.
The lines in the chart have outlines in the presentation.

It looks so:
[image: subplot diagram]

But normally, it should look like these:
[image: excel diagram]

Here is my actual code to create the subplot:
[image: subplot code]

PS: Sorry for the images. I'm at home and have no options to transfer data or go online with my work laptop.

Comment: You forgot to sort your values.

Comment: I load a sorted sql-query in a panda dataframe. I think it's okay so. But i test it again

Comment: Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
You are right.

I sorted my values in SQLite3 with 'ORDER BY DATE(xxx)'.
But it has to be: 'ORDER BY DATETIME(xxx)'.
Thanks a lot!